# Spring Mongo Auditing not working @CreatedDate @CreatedBy

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, auditing

I am using Spring Mongo Auditing and @CreatedDate @CreatedBy not working but @LastModifiedDate and @LastModifiedBy working fine.

I added @EnableMongoAuditing on a configuration class and also defined the AuditAware.

```
@Component("securityAuditorAware")
public class SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

 @Override
 public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityUtils.getUserPrincipal()).map(AuthenticatedUser::getIssuer);
 } 
}
```

Auditing class is :

```
@Document
public class Template  {

 @Id
 private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

 @CreatedDate
 private Date createdOn;
 @LastModifiedDate
 private Date modifiedOn;
 @CreatedBy
 private String createdBy;
 @LastModifiedBy
 private String modifiedBy;
}
```

When I save the document it put null in both **createdOn** and **createdBy** but the right values in both **modifiedOn** and **modifiedBy**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Entity does not inheritance `Persistable` interface, you should define a field which marked by `@Version` (org.springframework.data.annotation.Version).

```
@Document
public class Template {

 @Id
 private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

 @CreatedDate
 private Date createdOn;
 @LastModifiedDate
 private Date modifiedOn;
 @CreatedBy
 private String createdBy;
 @LastModifiedBy
 private String modifiedBy;
 @Version
 private Integer version;
}
```

In other side, if your entity  inheritance `Persistable` interface, you should implement logical which to detect the entity never been persisted before.

For more information, you can check two class: `PersistentEntityIsNewStrategy` and `PersistableIsNewStrategy`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue recently, and I did a bit of digging around to see how auditing actually works, so I am just putting it here in case any one else runs into the same problem.

First of all, here are relevant spring docs regarding auditing with regards to mongo:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing
- https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb
- https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/13/spring-data-2020-0-new-and-noteworthy-in-spring-data-mongodb-3-1

So auditing works via `EntityCallbacks` (defined in the `spring-data-commons` project) and the specific callback(s) that we need to run for mongo is either the `AuditingEntityCallback` or the `ReactiveAuditingEntityCallback` both defined in the `spring-data-mongodb` project.

Please note that all that these `EntityCallback`(s) does is to give either the `AuditingHandler` or `ReactiveAuditingHandler` in the `spring-data-commons` project a change to do their work, both of these classes extends the `AuditingHandlerSupport` abstract class and I would recommend putting a break point on the `isAuditable` method:

```java
    /**
     * Returns whether the given source is considered to be auditable in the first place.
     *
     * @param source must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return {@literal true} if the given {@literal source} considered to be auditable.
     */
    protected final boolean isAuditable(Object source) {

        Assert.notNull(source, "Source entity must not be null");

        return factory.getBeanWrapperFor(source).isPresent();
    }
```

Please note that the method above uses the property `factory` which is of type
`AuditingHandlerSupport` to get bean wrapper, and ultimatly decide if the object can be audited or not, so you are definitly going to want to step into that if you are running a debugger. There is only one class that extends it, the `DefaultAuditableBeanWrapperFactory` and then there is a class that extends that one in turn, the `MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory`. Both define the `getBeanWrapperFor` method, so if you are going to put breakpoints on this level add it to both classes.

Just out of interest I put my breakpoint in the `DefaultAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.getBeanWrapperFor` method and was quickly able to resolve my mistake:

```java
    /**
     * Returns an {@link AuditableBeanWrapper} if the given object is capable of being equipped with auditing information.
     *
     * @param source the auditing candidate.
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Optional<AuditableBeanWrapper<T>> getBeanWrapperFor(T source) {

        Assert.notNull(source, "Source must not be null");

        return Optional.of(source).map(it -> {

            if (it instanceof Auditable) {
                return (AuditableBeanWrapper<T>) new AuditableInterfaceBeanWrapper(conversionService, (Auditable<Object, ?, TemporalAccessor>) it);
            }

            AnnotationAuditingMetadata metadata = AnnotationAuditingMetadata.getMetadata(it.getClass());

            if (metadata.isAuditable()) {
                return new ReflectionAuditingBeanWrapper<T>(conversionService, it);
            }

            return null;
        });
    }
```

So I am on Spring Boot 2.7.3 which uses spring data commons 2.7.2 and spring data mongodb 3.4.2, and to fix my issue, (I use both blocking and reactive repositories), I had to add both two annotations to my data configuration:

```java
/** 
 ** NOTE @EnableMongoAuditing for blocking access
 ** NOTE @EnableReactiveMongoAuditing for reactive access 
 **/
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableReactiveMongoAuditing
public class MyProjectDataConfig
{
  // ...
}
```